# Animate a specific object on a specific Action with python

Tags: python, animation, import

I've been trying to add animations such as positions, rotations, scale and so on, you know, basic stuff, but i can't seem to apply this to a specific Action, or if i do, the values don't seem to be associated with the transform of the object.

here's my attempt to make it work:

```
def animate(data, obj):
#print("ANIM PHASE - " + obj.name);
for i in range(len(data.animations)):
    print(data.animations[i])
    ac = bpy.data.actions.get(data.animations[i].name)
    if (ac is None):
        ac = bpy.data.actions.new(data.animations[i].name)
    #Initial transform
    print(ac)
    #obj.keyframe_insert(data_path = "scale", frame = 1)
    fc = ac.fcurves.new(data_path = obj.name + ".scale", index = 0, action_group = "")
    new_key = fc.keyframe_points.insert(0, data.animations[i].ini_sca[0])
```

If i do obj.keyframe_insert, while the keyframe gets applied, it just gets applied to a brand new Action, and if i try to do it via FCurves, it gets associated to some sort of custom value that does nothing to the object.

Maybe this is a bit confusing, but i have not found an answer that i can fully understand on other questions that were previously being asked. Does anyone know what detail i'm missing?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do, but if you just want to insert keyframes, you don't need to explicitly access the actions.  You can simply add keyframes and they will be added to the action:  1) set the value you want to change, ie `obj.scale` and then call `obj.keyframe_insert()` but with `frame` set to the frame number you want the keyframe on, rather than 1.  What is `data` in your function?  (Example: `object.location = (0,0,0)<return>
object.keyframe_insert("location", frame = 1)`

Comment: data is an array that contains my keyframes from a file format i'm working on, so it has for example, frame 5, position [1,0,0]. The issue here is that i have several animations, and i want to store them in different actions. so i do actually want to insert the keyframes in specific actions instead of just raw keyframes. That's my issue right now, i can either create normal keyframes like you specified without being involved with actions, or not put them in actions properly. Hope that makes sense